# Красивый вывод бинарного дерева C#

Tags: c#, дерево

Написал структуру бинарного дерева, в которое можно добавлять элементы. Подскажи как можно сделать , чтобы можно было его красиво выводить в консоль в виде дерева именно , а не в строку. Искал в интернете примеры , но по шарпу мало чего нашел , в основном не то

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BinaryTree
{
    public class Tree
    {
        private int _size = 0;

        private class  TreeNode //Ветка
        {
            public char Value;
            
            public TreeNode Parent, Left, Right;
            
            public TreeNode(char value, TreeNode parent = null)
            {
                Left = null;
                Right = null;
                Parent = parent;
                Value = value;
            }
        }

        private TreeNode Root; //Корень
        public Tree()
        {
            Root = null;
        }
        
        
        public void Add(char value)
        {
            if (Root == null)
            {
                Root = new TreeNode(value);
                ++_size;
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode iterator = Root;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (value > iterator.Value)
                    {
                        if (iterator.Right != null) iterator = iterator.Right;
                        else
                        {
                            iterator.Right = new TreeNode(value, iterator);
                            ++_size;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (iterator.Left != null) iterator = iterator.Left;
                        else
                        {
                            ++_size;
                            iterator.Left = new TreeNode(value, iterator);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `чтобы можно было его красиво выводить` у каждого своё понятие о красоте. Будьте более конкретны и покажите, как вы сами пытались решить вашу проблему.

Comment: @tym32167, нужен просто вывод с выделением веток. Мои попытки не были успешными , поэтому сложно показать что-то конкретное

Comment: `просто вывод с выделением веток` я не понимаю этот текст. Вы можете хотя бы в текстовом файле руками в блокнооте нарисовать что вам надо?

Comment: `Мои попытки не были успешными` это понятно, иначе вопроса бы не было. Попытки надо показать, чтобы стала ясна ваша задача и можно было бы ваш код подправить, чтобы он заработал. Если же вы не показываете попыток, то вы попросту просите решить задачу за вас, что тут не приветсвуется.

Comment: @tym32167 добавил картинку пример

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649027

Comment: @Uranus на англоязычных ресурсах не смотрел, спасибо. Но если у кого то получится как в примере показано реализовать , буду очень благодарен

Comment: Реализовать как у вас на картинке сложнее - придется обходить дерево дважды, чтобы вычислить первоначальный отступ.

Comment: @Uranus попробую сам написать как представлено в том коде

Comment: Почему класс `TreeNode` вложенный, да еще и приватный? Покажите пример наполнения дерева тестовыми данными с картинки. К тому же нормальный вывод по образцу с картинки невозможен. Предствьте ситуацию, когда у соседей по две дочерние ноды, как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: @aepot данные abcdac так и хранятся в виде дерева , как показано в примере. TreeNode можно вынести , но я не думаю что что-то кардинально изменится

Comment: А как выводить, если в этом случае: https://pastebin.com/uqkPWK3X — если глубина дерева увеличится ещё на один уровень? Делать линии длиннее? Какие?

Comment: @VladD А никак, т.е. слишком сложно. Я тоже сначала пробовал сделать в тексте, но не получалось общего варианта, слишком много было каких-то магических констант, приходилось выравнивать через `.ToString("#0000")` числа, накладывать ограничения "положительные числа до тысячи" и просчитывать сколько паддингов ставить `.PadRight(MaxPad, '.')`, поэтому хоть я и не особо умею в графику - но в итоге оставил скетч в котором выглядит красиво. В текстовом виде самый лучший подход что я видел - этот тот, который скринул ссылку Uranus - дерево повёрнуто на 90 градусов.

Comment: @AK: Но там не видно бинарной структуры. Может, повернуть ещё на 90 градусов?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Готовый вариант не дам, но покажу как это сделано а) в графике б) для полных (complete) деревьев, посмотрите подход и сделаете по аналогии.

Основных идей будет две.

Во-первых, нужно помнить, что бинарное дерево [можно представить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1247517/213987) не столько в динамической форме, но и в форме массива. Для примера покажу из массива, но для неполного дерева можете написать какие угодно варианты - вполне возможно, что формулы окажутся проще.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-вторых, вам нужно хорошо знать зависимости между различными параметрами в бинарном дереве. Что-то я почерпнул отсюда: [complete binary tree](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/completeBinaryTree.html), что-то сам на листочке выписывал... Вот примерно это мне понадобилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и поехали (не всё, ключевые моменты):

Просто сгенерируем массив, это и будет наше дерево:

```
public int[] GenerateFullBinaryTreeRandom(int height)
{
    var t = (2 << height) - 1;
    var rand = new Random();
    
    return Enumerable.Repeat(1,t).Select(x => rand.Next(0,42)).ToArray();
}
```

И обойдём все узлы дерева, по пути отрисовывая их:

```
public static class TreeOrderHelper
{
    // ширина одной "клетки"
    private const int box = 50;

    public static void Display(this TreeNode root)
    {
        var canvas = new Canvas().Dump();

        if (root == null)
            return;

        var arr = root.ToArray();
        Display(arr, canvas);
    }

    private static void Display(int[] arr, Canvas canvas)
    {
        var h = TreeNodeExtension.LevesTotal(arr.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            DrawNode(arr[i].ToString(), canvas, GetX(h, i), GetY(i));

            if (h + 1 - TreeNodeExtension.CurrentLevel(i) == 1)
                continue;

            var xN = GetX(h, i);
            var yN = GetY(i);

            var xL = GetX(h, 2 * i + 1);
            var yL = GetY(2 * i + 1);

            var xR = GetX(h, 2 * i + 2);
            var yR = GetY(2 * i + 2);

            canvas.Children.Add(new Line { X1 = xN, Y1 = yN, X2 = xL, Y2 = yL, Stroke = Brushes.Gray, StrokeThickness = 0.5d });
            canvas.Children.Add(new Line { X1 = xN, Y1 = yN, X2 = xR, Y2 = yR, Stroke = Brushes.Gray, StrokeThickness = 0.5d });
        }
    }

    private static int GetX(int h, int i)
    {
        var l = TreeNodeExtension.CurrentLevel(i);
        var w1 = (int)Math.Pow(2, l - 1);
        var o = i - w1 + 1;
        var d = h + 1 - l;
        var f = (int)Math.Pow(2, d - 1) - 1;
        var s = (int)Math.Pow(2, d);
        var x = 20 + f * box + s * o * box;
        return x;
    }

    private static int GetY(int i)
    {
        var y = box * TreeNodeExtension.CurrentLevel(i);
        return y;
    }

    private static void DrawNode(string val, Canvas canvas, int x, int y)
    {
        const double PT_DM = 10;
        var e = new Ellipse
        {
            Width = PT_DM,
            Height = PT_DM,
            Margin = new Thickness(x - PT_DM / 2, y, 0, 0),
            Stroke = Brushes.Transparent,
            Fill = Brushes.SteelBlue,
            StrokeThickness = 0.5d,
        };

        var t = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = val,
            Margin = new Thickness(x + PT_DM / 2, y + PT_DM / 2, 0, 0),
            Foreground = Brushes.Gray,
        };

        canvas.Children.Add(e);
        canvas.Children.Add(t);
    }
}
```

И что-то ещё из этого extension'а понадобится:

```
public static class TreeNodeExtension
{
    public static TreeNode FromArray(this int[] arr)
    {
        if (!ValidateLength(arr.Length))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(arr.Length));

        return CreateTree(arr);
    }

    public static int[] ToArray(this TreeNode root)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        var queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();
        if (root != null) queue.Enqueue(root);
        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            var levelSize = queue.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < levelSize; i++)
            {
                var dequeued = queue.Dequeue();

                result.Add(dequeued.val);

                if (dequeued.left != null)
                    queue.Enqueue(dequeued.left);

                if (dequeued.right != null)
                    queue.Enqueue(dequeued.right);
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public static int LevesTotal(int length)
    {
        var total = 0;
        var i = 0;
        while(i < 32)
        {
            total = (1 << i) - 1;
            if (length <= total)
                break;
            i++;
        }
        if(length != total)
            throw new Exception();
            
        return i;
    }

    public static int CurrentLevel(int length)
    {
        var i = 1;
        var sum = 0;
        while (i < 32)
        {
            sum += 1 << (i -1);
            if (length + 1 <= sum)
                break;
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

На выходе отрисует примерно такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В текстовом виде у вас будут примерно такие же шаги по построению, но только будете рисовать виртуальные клетки и делать паддинги:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там есть пара подводных камней, поэтому я пока не доделал этот скрипт до конца. Сделаете - опубликуйте соседним ответом и поставьте галку.

PS Я свой код особо не оптимизировал, в своё время потратил пару недель только на то, чтобы написать рабочий прототип, поэтому если у кого-то будут идеи что и как улучшить - пишите, интересно. Топикстартер прав: по этой теме в интернете особо информации нет, да и в книгах тоже не особо.

Comment: Ого! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 5):

Как уже было сказано, решать задачу в текстовом режиме — не лучшая идея, поскольку наши углы наклона стрелок ограничены по сути ровно одним значением. Поэтому вот вам решение на WPF. Раз уж мы пользуемся WPF, то надо использовать существующий в поставке layout manager.

Поскольку дерево — рекурсивная структура данных, мы создадим рекурсивный `UserControl`. (Возможно, подход с кастомизацией TreeView был бы проще.)

Начнём с данных.

Кажется разумным определить такую структуру данных:

```cs
class BinaryTree<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public BinaryTree<T> Left { get; set; }
    public BinaryTree<T> Right { get; set; }
}
```

Но работать с неизвестным типом на уровне представления будет неудобно, поэтому добавим ещё и нетипизированный интерфейс:

```cs
interface IBinaryTree
{
    public object Value { get; }
    public IBinaryTree Left { get; }
    public IBinaryTree Right { get; }
}

class BinaryTree<T> : IBinaryTree
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public BinaryTree<T> Left { get; set; }
    public BinaryTree<T> Right { get; set; }

    object IBinaryTree.Value => Value;
    IBinaryTree IBinaryTree.Left => Left;
    IBinaryTree IBinaryTree.Right => Right;
}
```

Если вы захотите реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтобы WPF на лету подхватывал изменения, почему бы и нет.

Далее, наш контрол.

Для начала, положим вот такой XAML:

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Test.BinaryTreePresenter"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="150">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border CornerRadius="4" Padding="5,2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </Border>
        <local:BinaryTreePresenter DataContext="{Binding Left}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <local:BinaryTreePresenter DataContext="{Binding Right}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Такая штука не сработает, и немедленно приведёт к переполнению стека, ведь дерево контролов получается бесконечным. Даже установка триггера, который отключает Visibility при нулевом `DataContext`, не спасает. Значит, элементы нужно генерировать динамически. Для этого иcпользуется либо связка `ItemsPanel`/`ItemsHost`, либо code-behind. Давайте пойдём через code-behind, это, кажется, будет проще.

Поменяем в XAML строки

```xaml
<local:BinaryTreePresenter DataContext="{Binding Left}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<local:BinaryTreePresenter DataContext="{Binding Right}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
```

на

```xaml
<Decorator x:Name="LeftHost" DataContext="{Binding Left}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<Decorator x:Name="RightHost" DataContext="{Binding Right}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
```

А в code-behind напишем:

```cs
public partial class BinaryTreePresenter : UserControl
{
    public BinaryTreePresenter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LeftHost.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
        RightHost.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var host = (Decorator)sender;
        if (host.DataContext is IBinaryTree)
            host.Child ??= new BinaryTreePresenter();
        else
            host.Child = null;
    }
}
```

Запускаем, получаем:

[image: первый вариант]

Вроде бы всё хорошо, но не хватает стрелок. А также вертикального пространства, которое будут занимать стрелки.

Для начала, как сделать стрелки? Я не стал изобретать велосипед, а <s>украл</s> одолжил готовое решение [вот тут](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/04/191200.html).

В XAML добавим ещё один «этаж», в котором будет располагаться стрелка.

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Test.BinaryTreePresenter"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="150">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ClipToBounds="False" Height="30" Visibility="Collapsed"
                Name="ArrowHost">
            <local:ArrowLine x:Name="Arrow" Stroke="Black" />
        </Canvas>
        <Border CornerRadius="4" Padding="5,2" Name="ValueHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </Border>
        <Decorator x:Name="LeftHost" DataContext="{Binding Left}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Decorator x:Name="RightHost" DataContext="{Binding Right}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Затем, нам нужно задать элемент, *от* низа которого будет тянуться стрелка, то есть, родительский элемент. Но это должен не весь родительский `BinaryTreePresenter`, т. к. он охватывает наш элемент тоже. Нам нужен его `ValueHost` (для этого мы и дали ему имя, чтобы сослаться из code-behind).

В code-behind кладём поле `FrameworkElement parent;`, и присваиваем его, когда создаём внутренний элемент. Мы хотим соединить стрелкой середину верхнего узла с серединой нашего, для этого нам надо знать, когда положение или размер любого из этих элементов поменяется. (Можно сделать это один раз в начале, но тогда при изменении содержания узлов или добавлении/убирании веток стрелки не будут обновляться.)

Для этого я достал из старого проекта вот такой вспомогательный класс:

```cs
public class LayoutWatcher : IDisposable
{
    public LayoutWatcher(UIElement target)
    {
        this.target = target;
        target.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdate;
        oldRenderSize = target.RenderSize;
        oldRenderPosition = GetRenderPosition();
    }

    UIElement target;
    Size oldRenderSize;
    Point oldRenderPosition;

    void OnLayoutUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newRenderSize = target.RenderSize;
        var newRenderPosition = GetRenderPosition();

        var needUpdate = newRenderSize != oldRenderSize ||
                         newRenderPosition != oldRenderPosition;

        oldRenderSize = newRenderSize;
        oldRenderPosition = newRenderPosition;

        if (needUpdate)
            FireChanged();
    }

    Point GetRenderPosition() => target.TranslatePoint(new Point(), null);

    void FireChanged() => Changed?.Invoke(target, new EventArgs());

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Changed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        target.LayoutUpdated -= OnLayoutUpdate;
    }
}
```

Добавляем обработчик обытия `Loaded`, в котором мы будем устанавливать слежку за позицией и размерами обеих узлов. Симметрично, добавляем обработчик события `Unloaded`, в котором будем отписываться от изменений (чтобы не було утечек памяти). Получаем в итоге вот что:

```cs
public partial class BinaryTreePresenter : UserControl
{
    public BinaryTreePresenter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LeftHost.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
        RightHost.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
    }

    void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (parent is null)
            return;
        ArrowHost.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        selfWatcher = new LayoutWatcher(this);
        parentWatcher = new LayoutWatcher(this);
        selfWatcher.Changed += UpdateArrow;
        parentWatcher.Changed += UpdateArrow;
        UpdateArrow(null, null);
    }

    void UpdateArrow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var start = parent.TranslatePoint(new Point(parent.ActualWidth / 2, parent.ActualHeight), ArrowHost);
        Arrow.X1 = start.X;
        Arrow.Y1 = 0;
        Arrow.X2 = ActualWidth / 2;
        Arrow.Y2 = ArrowHost.ActualHeight - 2;
    }

    void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selfWatcher is not null)
        {
            selfWatcher.Changed -= UpdateArrow;
            selfWatcher.Dispose();
        }
        if (parentWatcher is not null)
        {
            parentWatcher.Changed -= UpdateArrow;
            parentWatcher.Dispose();
        }
    }

    FrameworkElement parent;
    LayoutWatcher selfWatcher, parentWatcher;

    void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var host = (Decorator)sender;
        if (host.DataContext is IBinaryTree)
            host.Child ??= new BinaryTreePresenter() { parent = ValueHost };
        else
            host.Child = null;
    }
}
```

Отдельных пояснений заслуживает функция `UpdateArrow`. В ней мы вычисляем при помощи `TranslatePoint` позицию нижней точки родительского узла относительно `ArrowHost`. Остальные координаты стрелки рассчитываются очевидным образом.

Получаем вот что:

[image: так-то получше будет, а?]

Всё!